# why ckan cannot use chinese?

Tags: ckan, server-error

I have installed Ckan by following the "from source" way. But after it was installed, i can't find chinese in the "language" Drop-dwon menu in the web page.

I checked the ckan i18n folder, and these are zh_CN and zh_TW in it. When i change the "locale_default" into zh_CN in the config file, there will be an error "default language zh_CN not available", and Ckan cannot run . I tried to install ckan several times, and every time met this problem.

Then i installed Ckan by the "from package" way. OK, i can find "中文（中国）"(chinese) in the drop-down menu, but when i create an dataset, and look into the dataset with language set as chinese, an error "Server error, an internal server error occured". But when i choose any other language, it will be ok.

Do any one know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both these issues are bugs. I've created two issues on the repository:

https://github.com/ckan/ckan/issues/3073

https://github.com/ckan/ckan/issues/3074

Thanks for flagging these

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I finally chose to install ckan from package, and modified formatter.py in line 147. I removed the _() function, and then i can create a dataset and enter it in the web page. It seems that the problem is about the time-stamp sting in the dataset web page.   Now that string can only be shown as chinese whichever language i choose.

Answer (score 0):

When you install ckan from package there is indeed a bug in the way that string formating works for the Chinese locale. This is because the translation string was mistakenly changed. You can fix this by changing the Chinese `ckan.po` file and recompiling it into the `.mo` file that is going to by `formatters.py`. That would be a cleaner workaround then changing the python file itself.

In order to do that `cd` into `/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/i18n/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES/` and edit line 962 (should start with `msgstr` and have header comment `# ckan/lib/formatters.py:146`). There you need to remove all the Chinese characters in curly braces and replace them with the English ones. It probably is easiest to just copy the string from `msgid` from one line above although you could also change the order of month, day, year here if you want...).

Once that is done use `msgfmt` (if not installed do `sudo apt install msgfmt`) to compile the translation strings again:

```
sudo msgfmt ckan.po -o ckan.mo
```

After that restart apache with `sudo service apache2 restart`. Now you should not see this error anymore.

Comment: Note that this should also be fixed with the next patch release.